# Make div's partially fill background of table cell

Tags: html, css, background, css-tables

I am currently struggling to create a table cell that has two div-containers left and right from the cell's content. These containers should take up the entire height of the cell and have some padding (10px). The problem is that the table cell has relativ heigth and width! So when I use relative height and width on the div's they do not show up.

Here is a example table cell:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| +-----------+                  +-----------+ |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |  div1     |                  |   div2    | |
| |           |      Some        |           | |
| |           |      Content     |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| |           |                  |           | |
| +-----------+                  +-----------+ |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

The div's have content and a background. Also I'd like to have the actual content centered vertically in the cell. The "content" is just a number, but the div's will have more content.

Here is a jsFiddle of the table as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/D46TQ/

I'd also like to avoid JavaScript. Simply because that way NoScript users will get the correct layout.

I was thinking about tables. But tables are a bad solution if they are not used for displaying content.

Comment: your middle content also need to wrap in a `div`.

Comment: I could not get this wrapper div to have the same dimensions as the table cell. (Relative height is causing some issues here!)

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a table inside the table cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the content section in a div, and add a wrapper class to the table cell. Then apply 'overflow:hidden'

```
#div1, #div2{
    width: 25%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:white;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

#content{
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Can you give me a working example? *(I.e. use jsFiddle for that purpose)*

Comment: my bad, forgot to add 'overflow:hidden' to '#content'. here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pprSF/

Comment: hmm... you are right. it works in chrome and ie. let me look into why it doesn't work in firefox

Comment: so, what i noticed is that if i put any content into the side divs, they get displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/pprSF/4/ will that work for you? or do you need those divs to display with no content as well?

Comment: They will have content. But they are supposed to extend all over the background. (The height should be the cell's height)